# jQuery UI tab with Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery Tab with two tabs. Each of the tabs loads contents from two different pages. Parent Page has a Div for jQuery UI Dialog.

When the page is loaded first time and I click a link in the 1st Tab the UI Dialog opens and works perfectly as expected. Now I go to tab 2 and then come back. Then I press the same link. The UI dialog does not open.

I'm using struts1 (JAVA).

**Parent Page Scripts**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#addHrsDet").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        height : 600,
        close : closeHours,
        width : 900
    });
});

<div id="addHrsDet" title="Add Minutes">
        <iframe id="addHrsDetIframe" width="100%" height="100%"
            marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto"
            title="Add Minutes">Your browser does not support</iframe>
</div>
```

**Tab 1**

```
function editPrjHours(prjId, menuId, prjHourId) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache : false
    });
    $("#addHrsDetIframe").attr(
            "src",
            "addhrs.do?prj=" + prjId + "&menuId=" + menuId + "&prjHourId="
                    + prjHourId + "&hm=true");
    $("#addHrsDet").dialog("open");
}
```

**Tab 2 is empty**

**EDIT**

On checking the firbug I see an error **TypeError: $("#addHrsDet").dialog is not a function**